# Is mono.security.dll not needed in new 3x version?

Tags: postgresql, mono, npgsql

downloading new version of npgsql i could See is not compiled old mono.security dll file. Is Not needed in newest version? I have not to ad any reference to this library if i use 3x version?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct - Mono.Security.dll is no longer needed in Npgsql 3.x. You don't need to add any reference to any external library in order to use Npgsql 3.x.